# MacOSX PyQt grabbing an area outside the screen

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyqt

Is it possible for pyqt to  grabbing an area outside the screen?

This is my code, and what it does is it grabbing itself and shows it

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import os

from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *

class test_widget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(test_widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.__ui__()

    def __ui__(self):
        t_lay_parent = QVBoxLayout()
        self.pushButton_open = QPushButton("Screen")
        self.label_image = QLabel()
        t_lay_parent.addWidget(self.pushButton_open)
        t_lay_parent.addWidget(self.label_image)
        self.pushButton_open.clicked.connect(self.slt_open)
        self.setLayout(t_lay_parent)

    def slt_open(self):
        self.full_screen = QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().grabWindow(long(0), self.x(), self.y(), self.width(), self.height())
        self.label_image.setPixmap(self.full_screen)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = test_widget()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is what the program looks like when it's running.
[image]
[image]

It doesn't capture itself completely, and my expectation is that it can capture itself completely, including the area outside the screen

I tried the qwidget.grab() method, and it can grab itself completely. However, when a program embeds an external window, it cannot grab the external window.
[image]
[image]

Comment: According to Qt docs. "The grabWindow() function grabs pixels from the screen, not from the window", so this function is't able to grab invisible parts of your widget.

Comment: Yes, I know that the grabWindow function grabs pixels from the screen, and I want to know if it's possible to grab the region outside the screen?